# Calculate downtime in stream analytics query

Tags: azure, stream, azure-stream-analytics, data-stream

we've input data like -
[image]

Where
**plc_id** is the id of a particular PLC
**zero-speed** - 0 means machine is running, 1 means machine is stopped.

We want to calculate the downtime and store it into the sql.
Here is the stream analytics query We've written -

```
WITH SelectPreviousEvent AS
(
SELECT
    *,
    LAG([time]) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(hour, 24)) as previous_time,
    LAG([zero-speed]) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(hour, 24)) as previous_speed,
    LAG([plc_id]) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(hour,24)) as previous_plc,
    [plc_id]
FROM [iot-input] TIMESTAMP BY [time]
)
-- selects time when current_speed is equal to 1 and previous_speed is equal to 0
SELECT 
    LAG(time) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(hour, 24) WHEN previous_speed = 0 ) [started_time],
    previous_time [end_time],
    [plc_id],
    [created_by] = 'Stream Analytics',
    [updated_by] = 'Stream Analytics',
    [duration] = DATEDIFF(second, LAG(time) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(hour, 24) WHEN previous_speed = 0 ), previous_time)
INTO [sql-output]
FROM SelectPreviousEvent
WHERE
    [zero-speed] = 0
    AND previous_speed = 1
```

It is working as expected when there is data from only one plc_id.

**Output** -
[image]

And we've verified this downtime with customer, they said its correct.

But if we want to calculate downtime for multiple PLCs, like if there is one more PLC called **plc5** and it is also sending the data like **plc4**, we're getting unexpected results.

I've written few other queries but none of them worked. I couldn't get much help from documentation on this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `PARTITION BY plc_id` in `LAG` so that the calculation is done for that **plc_id** only. See [that doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/lag-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) for more info.

Here that gives:

```
...
    LAG([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY plc_id LIMIT DURATION(hour, 24)) as previous_time,
    LAG([zero-speed]) OVER (PARTITION BY plc_id LIMIT DURATION(hour, 24)) as previous_speed,
...
```

You shouldn't use it for `LAG(plc_id)`, or else you will get the same plc_id. But you should need it again for the following calculations.

Comment: Florian, it worked as expected.